# How can I get current job-name in SageMaker training job script?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I write some training job on AWS-SageMaker framework.

For some it's requirements, it needs know the job-name of which current running on.

I know this code works for it ...

```
import sagemaker_containers
env = sagemaker_containers.training_env()
job_name = env['job_name']
```

But `sagemaker_containers` package has been deprecated. (I read that on [it's GitHub](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-containers))

What should i do?

I just started learning about this platform last month. I would appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For older containers using the deprecated `sagemaker_containers`, the approach you described is correct.

For newer containers that use [`sagemaker-training-toolkit`](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit), this is how you retrieve information about the environment: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit#get-information-about-the-container-environment

```py
from sagemaker_training import environment

env = environment.Environment()

job_name = env["job_name"]
```

You can check the [DLC Release Notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deep-learning-containers/latest/devguide/dlc-release-notes.html) to see what's installed in each version.